# css button right property ignored

Tags: html, css, firefox

I'm trying to stretch a button across a variable width space so that the ends are anchored to its container edges using the left and right properties like this:

```
<button style="position: absolute; left: 0px; right: 0px;">Test</button>
```

This works as expected in Chrome, IE, and Safari. The button stretches across the width of the browser window. However, in FireFox/SeaMonkey and Opera, the right property is ignored and the button is just wide enough to hold the caption. Why is that?

Comment: is the parent set to `position:relative` and has been given a width? Show an example

Comment: 100% only works if left and right are 0. What if I want left and right to be 100px? Note that right will work if I also specify a width value.

Comment: Of course I could just anchor a DIV with the desired left and right properties and put the button inside that at 100% width but it's stupid I have to resort to that.

Comment: D'oh, looks like you beat me to it.

Comment: Units ('px') are not needed for zero values

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the only way around it is to absolute position a div with a button inside it, set to 100% width. Like so:

```
<body>
  <div style="width: 600px; height: 600px; position: relative;">
    <div style="position: absolute; left: 0px; right: 0px;">
      <button style="width:100%;">Test</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Here is a live working example to play with http://jsbin.com/aweleq/2/edit

It's a known bug https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=471763

Answer (score 0):

Why not define your left and right space in the parent Element of your button and set the Button itself to 100% width. Isn't that stupid i think.

```html
<div>
    <button>Test</button>
<div>
```

```css
div {
    padding-left: 40px;
    padding-right: 60px;
}

button {
     width: 100%;
}​
```

You can also set them to position relative/absolute if you want to.

​

Comment: Sticking padding in there prevents other things from being placed next to it. Anchoring the outer div to left and right positions is what I ended up doing. But the fact that half the browsers do it one way and the other half another is a problem.

Answer (score 0):

The basic issue here is whether `<button>` is a replaced element.  The rules for replaced elements and non-replaced elements are different; compare http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#abs-non-replaced-width and http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#abs-replaced-width

It looks like Firefox and Opera treat `<button>` as a replaced element here while your version of IE and WebKit do not.  Unfortunately, nothing actually defines whether this element is a replaced element.

But note that WebKit generally gets this part of the spec wrong, even for things that are definitely replaced elements.  See https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=81863